# how to make a variable take a html link without formatting in python?

Tags: python, runtime-error

I need  to take a url input and use it in subprocess.call().how is it possible?
I wanted to write a loop so that it keeps on downloading images until required by doing this

```
for i in range(1,tot):
    subprocess.call(["wget","http://z.mfcdn.net/store/manga/10543/01-003.0/compressed/beelzebub_3.beelzebub_ch003_%02d.jpg"%num])
```

to automate this further. is there any way so that the user gives input like `http://z.mfcdn.net/store/manga/10543/01-003.0/compressed/beelzebub_3.beelzebub_ch003_%02d.jpg` and I can directly insert the variable into subprocess.call().

I Tried the following

```
urlin=raw_input("input the url: ")
for i in range(1,tot):
    subprocess.call(["wget",urlin\"%num"])
```

but it is not working.how to make it work.Hope you understood my problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `i` as the iterator for your loop but you use an undeclared `num`.
Here is what I came up with (working on my computer):

```
import subprocess

numberImages = 3
urlin=raw_input("input the url: ")
for i in range(1,numberImages+1):
    print urlin%i
    subprocess.call(["wget",urlin%i])
```

used `http://z.mfcdn.net/store/manga/10543/01-003.0/compressed/beelzebub_3.beelzebub_ch003_%02d.jpg`as raw_input

here is my output:

```
input the url: http://z.mfcdn.net/store/manga/10543/01-003.0/compressed/beelzebub_3.beelzebub_ch003_%02d.jpg
http://z.mfcdn.net/store/manga/10543/01-003.0/compressed/beelzebub_3.beelzebub_ch003_01.jpg
#Some wget download debug
http://z.mfcdn.net/store/manga/10543/01-003.0/compressed/beelzebub_3.beelzebub_ch003_02.jpg
#Some wget download debug
http://z.mfcdn.net/store/manga/10543/01-003.0/compressed/beelzebub_3.beelzebub_ch003_03.jpg
#Some wget download debug
```

Comment: Can you please explain how the url%i works? the code is perfect but I am still not able to grasp how url%i works

Comment: This works the same way as in your original question:

http://___URL____ch003_%02d.jpg"%i , `%02d` means that this will be replaced by a variable (`i`). This variable is a decimal (`d`) and the result will be a 2-digit number (`02`). If i<=9 there will be a leading 0 in order to properly have a 2 digit number. Else, this will just be replaced by `i`. Now, `urlin%i` works the same way as `urlin` contains your raw_input which is http://___URL____ch003_%02d.jpg

More informations on string formatting at
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm paragraph "String Formatting Operator"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!!